# Initializing AngularJS controller member

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an [html](/questions/tagged/html)/[angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) form that submits data to my webserver. The page is loading the controller because it does execute the submit function. I get an `"ReferenceError: formData is not defined"` error when I reference `formData` data. I thought this was the proper way to initialize members of a controller.

```
var app = angular.module('messagingForm', []);
app.controller('messagingController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.formData = {
    userName: "bob",
    email: "bob@bob.com",
    subject: "why",
    message: "why not?"
  };

  $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
  $scope.submit = function(sendContact) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

    console.log('validating data');
    if (sendContact.$valid) {
      console.log('sending data');
      $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'email.php',
        data: {
          'name': formData.userName,
          'email': formData.email,
          'subject': formData.subject,
          'message': formData.message
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        } //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
      }).success(function(data) {

      });
    } else {

      console.log('validating not good');
      alert('failed');
    }
  }
});
```

I'm unclear how I initialize a member variable I guess. what is the right way to do this?

Matt.

Comment: Show the HTML the controller is bound to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

Change:

```
data: {
       'name': formData.userName,
       'email': formData.email,
       'subject': formData.subject,
       'message': formData.message
    },
```

to

```
data: {
   'name': $scope.formData.userName,
   'email': $scope.formData.email,
   'subject': $scope.formData.subject,
   'message': $scope.formData.message
},
```

**Then:**

```js
var app = angular.module('messagingForm', []);
app.controller('messagingController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.formData = {
    userName: "bob",
    email: "bob@bob.com",
    subject: "why",
    message: "why not?"
  };

  $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
  $scope.submit = function(sendContact) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

    console.log('validating data');
    if (sendContact.$valid) {
      console.log('sending data');
      $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'email.php',
        data: {
          'name': $scope.formData.userName,
          'email': $scope.formData.email,
          'subject': $scope.formData.subject,
          'message': $scope.formData.message
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        } //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
      }).success(function(data) {

      });
    } else {

      console.log('validating not good');
      alert('failed');
    }
  }
});
```

Because in your code, «formaData» it doesn't exist in the context. You might try also declaring a local variable, something like this:

```
var formData = {
    userName: "bob",
    email: "bob@bob.com",
    subject: "why",
    message: "why not?"
};
```

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('messagingForm', []);
app.controller('messagingController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var formData = {
        userName: "bob",
        email: "bob@bob.com",
        subject: "why",
        message: "why not?"
    };

    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(sendContact) {
        $scope.submitted = true;

        console.log('validating data');
        if (sendContact.$valid) {
            console.log('sending data');
            $http({
                method  : 'post',
                url     : 'email.php',
                data : {
                    'name': formData.userName,
                    'email': formData.email,
                    'subject': formData.subject,
                    'message': formData.message
                },
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).success(function(data){

            });
        } else {

            console.log('validating not good');
            alert('failed');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok that is the answer.   Why do I have to use $scope in a function that is a member of the controller?   I assume its not like a Java or C# this member which is implicitly included all references to member data?

Comment: $scope is an object that refers to the application model. In this scenario you're declaring an object inside $scope.
$scope.formaData = {}; Similarly you could use: var formData = {};

Here a reference about $scope https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. I hope this helps you.

Comment: You need to specify $scope in your controller to get the context where the model is stored so that controllers, directives and expressions can access it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create the `formData` object as a constant and then explicitly pass it in to the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('messagingForm', []).constant("formData", {
  'userName': 'bob',
  'email': 'bob@bob.com',
  'subject': 'why',
  'message': 'why not?'
});
app.controller('messagingController', function($scope, $http, formData) {
```

Rest of you code here...

It just makes it a little clearer and easier to test.